# Google Apps Script: Why am I getting 'The parameters (String,number) don't match' error?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Question: I'm trying to get conditional borderline differ from varient input data via Google Apps Script.
But, I keep getting same Error message and can't tell what's the issue.
What do I miss in the code?

1. Error message I got is below :

> Exception: The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.

2. Code I wrote is below :

```
    function myBorder() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'))
    for(var i=1; i < 20 ; i++)for( j=1; j<20; j++){
    if(spreadsheet.getRange(i,j).getValue().length>0)
 spreadsheet.getRange(i,j).setBorder(true,true,true,true,null,null,"black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID-MEDIUM)
    if(spreadsheet.getRange(i,j).getValue()=='공란')
       spreadsheet.getRange(i,j).setBorder(true,true,true,false,null,null,"black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID).setBackground("#E2E2E2")
  }}
```

3. What i've tried to get specific cell with specific date data(failed)

```
else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(val) == "[object Date]" && Date.val == '2999. 1. 1') {
      range.setBorder(true, false, true, true, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID).setBackground("#E2E2E2");}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using .getRange() on a Spreadsheet class object, it only accepts A1 Notation. What you want to do is use .getRange(i, j) on a Sheet class object. Adding this line after setting the active sheet would fix this:

```
spreadsheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
```

However this can be further simplified. Here are two versions of the complete function. First, with different formats for each of your data types:

```js
function myBorder() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) for (j = 1; j < 20; j++) {
    var range = spreadsheet.getRange(i, j);
    var val = range.getValue();
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(val) == "[object Date]") {
      range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, "blue", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED).setBackground("mistyrose");
    } else if (typeof val == 'number') {
      range.setBorder(true, true, true, false, null, null, "green", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED).setBackground("powderblue");
    } else if (val == '공란') {
      range.setBorder(true, true, true, false, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID).setBackground("#E2E2E2");
    } else if (typeof val == 'string' && val.length > 0) {
      range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
    }
  }
}
```

Second, with one format for all data types:

```js
function myBorder() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) for (j = 1; j < 20; j++) {
    var range = spreadsheet.getRange(i, j);
    var val = range.getValue();
    if (val == '공란') {
      range.setBorder(true, true, true, false, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID).setBackground("#E2E2E2");
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(val) == "[object Date]" || typeof val == 'number' || typeof val == 'string' && val.length > 0) {
      range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
    }
  }
}
```

To improve efficiency, we can build a **RangeList** array for each value type. To separate numbers from currencies without checking the cell formatting (too slow), we can test the display value against an array of currency characters.

There is also an added variable for looking for a specific date. Currently, this ignores the GMT timezone because Daylight Savings Time was being ignored on one end. Someone else might know better how to account for that.

```js
function myBorder() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var specDate = new Date(2023, 2, 2);
  var rows = 20;
  var columns = 20;
  var array = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).getValues();
  var display = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).getDisplayValues();

  var currencies = ["Lek", "؋", "\\$", "ƒ", "₼", "৳", "Br", "BZ\\$", "\\$b", "KM", "P", "лв", "R\\$", "៛", "¥", "₡", "kn", "₱", "Kč", "kr", "RD\\$", "£", "€", "¢", "Q", "L", "Ft", "₹", "Rp", "﷼", "₪", "J\\$", "₩", "₭", "ден", "RM", "₨", "₮", "د.إ", "MT", "C\\$", "₦", "B/\\.", "Gs", "S/\\.", "zł", "lei", "₽", "Дин.", "S", "R", "CHF", "NT\\$", "฿", "TT\\$", "₺", "₴", "\\$U", "Bs", "₫", "Z\\$"];

  var spec = [];
  var date = [];
  var cur = [];
  var num = [];
  var blank = [];
  var string = [];

  for (i = 1; i < rows; i++)
    for (j = 1; j < columns; j++) {
      var val = array[i - 1][j - 1];
      var disp = display[i - 1][j - 1];
      var r1c1 = `R${i}C${j}`;
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(val) == "[object Date]") {
        if (val.toString().split('GMT')[0] == specDate.toString().split('GMT')[0]) {
          spec.push(r1c1);
        } else date.push(r1c1);
      } else if (typeof val == 'number') {
        if (val != disp && currencies.some(e => new RegExp(e).test(disp))) {
          cur.push(r1c1);
        } else num.push(r1c1);
      } else if (typeof val == 'string' && val.length > 0) {
        if (val == '공란') {
          blank.push(r1c1);
        } else string.push(r1c1);
      }
    }

  if (spec.length) spreadsheet.getRangeList(spec).setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, "blue", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK).setBackground("mistyrose");
  if (date.length) spreadsheet.getRangeList(date).setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, "blue", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED).setBackground("mistyrose");
  if (num.length) spreadsheet.getRangeList(num).setBorder(true, true, true, false, null, null, "green", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED).setBackground("powderblue");
  if (cur.length) spreadsheet.getRangeList(cur).setBorder(true, true, true, false, null, null, "green", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED).setBackground("cyan");
  if (blank.length) spreadsheet.getRangeList(blank).setBorder(true, true, true, false, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID).setBackground("#E2E2E2");
  if (string.length) spreadsheet.getRangeList(string).setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);

}
```

Comment: @millizard One more quick question here. With the code you're suggesting, it works with cells filled with string(letter). But it doesn't work with cells filled with numbers like currency(money) and date. Is there any specific way to apply this code to number-based data?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include two versions that also work for numbers and dates. The first is for different border formats, and the second is for one border format for all 3 types (string, number, date).

Comment: *milklizard Thank you. Your solution works for my sheet. Sorry for naggying you, i got few more related question. 1) Is there any way to improve speed of running this code? (It takes almost a minute to run this code. I'm suspecting selecting location with [i,j] way increases running time.) 2) How can i select a cell with specific date(ex.2023.3.1) to give specific cell borderline? (I've tried this way, but it didn't work.(Posted on my question) 3) Can i choose cell with currency data(such as '100$') and give it borderline style different from general 'number' type cell?

Comment: You are correct that it is slow because it calls on one cell at a time. You'll find this new version much more efficient, updating once per type.